# Select2 and Ember.js - can't set initial value

Tags: ember.js, jquery-select2

Today I've spent many hours trying to figure out what's wrong. I'm trying to set an initial value once some data is loaded via `content.isLoaded`. This is done after `CreditCards` and `CardProviders` content is loaded as you can see in the attached photo:[image: attached photo]. But somehow it can't set this value:

```
selectDefaultValue: (->
  if !@get 'multiple'
    console.log 'content loaded'
    window.$select = @$('.filter-select').first()
    # get provider id
    id = $('#ember-container').attr('data-providerId')
    console.log 'id: ', id
    $select.select2 'val', id
).observes('controller.controllers.application.canSetDefaultProvider')
```

But when I try `window.$select` from the console it works!

`canSetDefaultProvider` is set to true when both `CreditCards` and `CardProviders` content is loaded.